# Gdx.files.internal() not loading my .fnt file

Tags: java, file, fonts, libgdx, loading

So I am working through a tutorial book from packtpub on libgdx to learn how the framework works. Anyways, up until this point I have had no problems. I am trying to get a BitmapFont to load, and no matter what I do it tells me that it is not there. Here is the code;

```
     public AssetFonts(){
        //Create 3 Fonts using VCRFONT
        defaultSmall = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("images/vcr.fnt"), true);
        defaultNormal = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("images/vcr.fnt"), true);
        defaultBig = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("images/vcr.fnt"), true);
```

I am getting this exception error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading font file: images/vcr.fnt
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.load(BitmapFont.java:667)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.<init>(BitmapFont.java:481)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.<init>(BitmapFont.java:116)
at com.dijdesign.libgdx.game.util.Assets$AssetFonts.<init>(Assets.java:41)
at com.dijdesign.libgdx.game.util.Assets.init(Assets.java:79)
at com.dijdesign.libgdx.game.CanyonBunnyMain.create(CanyonBunnyMain.java:25)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Missing: file

This is very frustrating, I went in to the font file as well to edit it, the two things I edited were just deleting from the info face= && page id= fields here is that code;

```
info face="" size=32 bold=0 italic=0 charset="" unicode=0 stretchH=100 smooth=1 aa=1 padding=0,0,0,0 spacing=1,1
```

common lineHeight=80 base=26 scaleW=128 scaleH=64 pages=1 packed=0 alphaChnl=1 redChnl=0 greenChnl=0 blueChnl=0
page id=0 file=""

I have spent some time looking through other answers that are similar to this but I cannot get it to work. If anyone knows how to help that would be great, feel free to ask me anything that will help direct you to the right answer, or if you know of a question w/ answer that fixes my problem please let me know. Also if interested the book I am using is Learning LibGDX Game Development 2nd Edition, and I am on section 5.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .fnt file isn't going to work without an image file to render. What you pasted got messed up by the formatting here, but it looks like you have `file=""` in the .fnt file, which would cause just the error you're getting. I don't know where you got this particular .fnt file, but it should have both a .fnt and (usually) a .png part to it, with the .fnt having a reference to the .png in the earlier file section, such as `file="vcr.png"` if you have that png in the same folder. Folders can be tricky with .fnt, and I'd suggest keeping the .fnt and .png in the same folder at the base of your libGDX assets directory (often assets/ is in the Android project, or in core if you don't have an Android project). If you want to try some other fnt files to see if they fit your visuals better (or just work), I keep several for distribution [in this folder of a GitHub repo](https://github.com/tommyettinger/Glamer/tree/master/premade). You should definitely make sure you have both the matching .fnt and .png, no matter where the files are from.

As an aside, creating 3 different BitmapFont files from the same .fnt won't change the image it uses, although you can get each pixel in the image to be shown bigger for a certain font if you enlarge that BitmapFont later. It's common to generate multiple sizes of a BitmapFont using a tool like [Hiero, at the bottom of this page](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/tools.html), which allows detail to be higher on larger fonts, or as you get more comfortable with libGDX to use FreeTypeFontGenerator to produce correctly-sized fonts at runtime. Personally, I use either distance field fonts to smoothly scale (which is not an easy technique to get up and running, but looks nice in text-heavy games) or I intentionally go for a retro-look and scale the font in integer increments (double size, triple size, etc. but not 150% size because it would cause unpleasant scaling with pixel fonts).

Comment: Also, since you said you deleted the `page id=0`, that probably shouldn't have been removed, since it might be a necessary part of the .fnt file, and probably is needed to find the correct image for the font. I don't know if `face` is safe to remove either, and it's not a good idea to assume they can be removed without verifying that they are extraneous.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I was using shoebox to generate my .fnts and it messed them up. I was wanting to use Heiro, but couldn't find it for the life of me! Thanks for linking me to it, I got it working now!